# Sub class throwing AttributeError rather than getting properties from super class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super, superclass

I have a classes `ConfTest` and  `SubConfigTest` which looks like this:

```
class ConfTest():
    config = {
        'account': Account
    }

    def __init__(self,
                 account):
        self.account = account
        ...



class SubConfigTest(ConfTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubConfigTest, self).__init__(account=self.account)
        self.path = install_test(self.ver_config)
```

I want `SubConfigTest` to have all the properties of `ConfTest`.

When I run my program I get this error:

```
super(SubConfigTest, self).__init__(account=self.account,
AttributeError: 'SubConfigTest' object has no attribute 'account'
```

Where am I going wrong? I feel like I must declare `account` somewhere in `SubConfigTest` but I'm not sute how or where. I only added it because if I leave it out I get an error saying:

```
super(SubConfigTest, self).__init__()
```

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the `SubConfigTest.__init__(...`. Using `self.account` with `super(...` is useless and will fail, as `self.account` exists **not** before `super(...` has finished.

Comment: @stovfl, I've provided some more info. There is very little in my `__init__()` though.

Comment: You didn't pass a starting account value to `SubConfigTest`, therefore you initialize with `super().__init__(account=0)`. Read [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In line `super(SubConfigTest, self).__init__(account=self.account)` the part `account=self.account` is evaluated before calling `__init__` of base class, where is the definition `self.account = account`, that's why the error occures. You probably forget to pass `account` as a parameter to `SubConfigTest.__init__`:

```
class SubConfigTest(ConfTest):
    def __init__(self, account):
        super(SubConfigTest, self).__init__(account=account)
        self.path = install_test(self.ver_config)
```